# can I create a resource group in one subscription using other subscription endpoint in vsts CD task?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I am modifying a CD pipeline.
I have a azure powershell task to create app insight using powershell.
Argument passed:

```
-SubscriptionName $(SubscriptionName) -ResourceGroupName $(ResourceGroupName) -clientID $(clienttestID) -AccessKey $(AccesstestKey)
```

The `ResourceGroup(ResourceGroupName)` is available on `SubscriptionName(SubscriptionName ~~abc)` and I am using Azure Subscription connection `xyz`.
Is this a correct scenario, or will it fail as resource group on which I am creating app insight is under different subscription?

Answer (score 0):

```
       To create any resources using powershell, you need to be logged in to the same subscription account in which your resource group exist otherwise it will give you an error like below
```

[image]

```
       In order to create a application insight under a resource group after switching to a right subscription, you can follow below steps:-



# Connect-AzureRmAccount / Connect-AzureRmAccount
# Set the name of the Application Insights Resource

$appInsightsName = "SampleApp"

# Set the application name used for the value of the Tag "AppInsightsApp" 

$applicationTagName = "My-Sample-App"

# Set the name of the Resource Group to use.  
# Default is the application name.
$resourceGroupName = "My-RG"

###################################################
# Create the Resource and Output the name and iKey
###################################################

Get-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName "Sample Subscription name"

# Select the azure subscription
Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName "Sample Subscription name"

# Create the App Insights Resource

$resource = New-AzureRmResource -ResourceName $appInsightsName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Tag @{ applicationType = "web"; applicationName = $applicationTagName} -ResourceType "Microsoft.Insights/components" -Location "East US" -PropertyObject @{"Application_Type"="web"} -Force

# Give owner access to the team

New-AzureRmRoleAssignment `
  -SignInName "myteam@sampleDomain.com" `
  -RoleDefinitionName Owner `
  -Scope $resource.ResourceId 


# Display iKey
Write-Host "App Insights Name = " $resource.Name
Write-Host "IKey = " $resource.Properties.InstrumentationKey
```

Once the resource would be added, you will be able to see the details for it like below-

[image]